# How to retrieve wsdl from deployed web service in TEA 2.2?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I have deployed a web service in TEA 2.2, now I am unable to retrieve the wsdl from the deployed service.

These are the URLs that I am trying for wsdl.

```
> https://localhost:8989/sn_assyst/ws_ent_itsm_sn_assyst_v1.0.0/Service+De... 
> https://localhost:8989/SNtoASSYST?wsdl
```

Comment: Which BW version are you using?

Comment: Hi, 
I am using TIBCO BW 6.3.3. When I concat '?wsdl' to the service URL, then I am getting the following error.

>> Message : No standalone definition available for soap binding.

Comment: How did you define the soap binding for the component?

Comment: Hi,   this is Soap/ Http, and the endpoint is :  /SOAPServiceBinding/sNtoASSYST/;   SOAP version : 1.1;  Style: Document;  Encoding: Literal,  Attachment Style : SwA; Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: If the endpoint is  /SOAPServiceBinding/sNtoASSYST/, then the URL must be   https://localhost:8989/SOAPServiceBinding/sNtoASSYST/?wsdl.

Comment: yes, it deployed on TIBCO dev server.  I am using the below url's, but getting message - No standalone definition available for soap binding.                            > http://tibDEVserver:9288/SOAPServiceBinding/sNtoASSYST/?wsdl

(proxy)> https://abcdxyz.com/dev/sn_assyst/SOAPServiceBinding/sNtoASSYST/?wsdl                                                                                              > is there any other way to fetch the wsdl?

Comment: Ensure that you can call the ws using tibDEVserver:9288/SOAPServiceBinding/sNtoASSYST URL

Comment: You can generate the wsdl from studio if that doesn't work

Comment: yes, I am able to call the web service in SoapUI using the url  > tibDEVserver:9288/SOAPServiceBinding/sNtoASSYST/